# Local DNS before it hits Google's DNS

Tags: google-chrome, dns

Is there a way to automatically bind a custom name/query to an IP or a domain?

Much like the way "localhost" is an alias for 127.0.0.1, e.g. "machine1" mapping to a particular machine's IP; I'd like it to be possible to also work offline. I imagine it would be great for developers to work with an alias in Chrome, or preferably even more globally. Much like SSH also works.

Comment: localhost is defined by the hosts file, so I imagine you'd need to add a line to that file with the mapping from your alias to the IP.

Comment: @devlincarnate `curl` works for that, thanks a lot! Google Chrome doesn't know about the alias, though.

Comment: no, this would be browser independent.  just be aware that some antivirus / antimalware programs prevent modification of the hosts file since you could easily map google.com to a malicious IP, for example

Comment: Prefixing with "http://" does work though. Improvement...